# System.Diagnostic.TraceError not working in Release configuration

Tags: c#, debugging, azure, azure-web-app-service, trace

I have TraceError statement configured in my application. TraceError statement is listened by Azure listener when app is deployed in Debug mode but Azure listener doesn't work when Web app is published in Release mode.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think the compiler will optimize the code and move things around, it loses the relationship between source code and compiled assembly code. If you compile in debug mode the relationship can be maintained, but in release mode it cannot.

Comment: TRACE should work just fine in Release configuration as it's defined for both Debug and Release configuration. Isn't it ?

Comment: have you turned on Application diagnostics on in the settings of that azure web app? also try setting trace level at "verbose"

Comment: Yes, I have turned on the Application Diagnostic on in Azure Portal and have the trace level set to verbose.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have same issue with framework 5.4.2 and VS 2015

Comment: Yes, Have you configured diagnosticconfiguration ?
How are you publishing via Visual Studio or Powershell script ?